# Custom validation rule using other field as part of validation logic in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I have a custom form request that has 2 fields `amount` and `currency`.

There is some validation rules for which amounts are allowed, but they are determined by what the currency is.

So I want to create a custom `ValidAmountRule` which can determine the max and min amount based on the currency.

How can I access the currency attribute from a validation rule on the amount field?

Comment: can you please show me your code ?

Comment: Have you defined a custom rule yet? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules. Once you do, you should just be able to call `new ValidAmountRule($request->input('currency_type'))` (or similar, depending on how you're indicating this currency)

Comment: For custom things I usually use this
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#using-rule-objects

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
'amount' => [
    'required',
    function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
        // using global helper function
        if (request()->currency === 'foo' && request()->amount < 100) {
            $fail('The Amount has to be above 100 if currency is foo');
        }
         
        // or incase you are using a Form Request and don't like using 
        // global helper functions
        if ($this->input('currency') === 'foo' && $this->input('amount') < 100) {
            $fail('The Amount has to be above 100 if currency is foo');
        }

    },
],
```

Source: [Laravel Custom Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$request->validate([
    'currency' => 'required',
    'amount'   => 'required_if:currency, USD|numeric|between:1,100',
    'amount'   => 'required_if:currency, EUR|numeric|between:1,50',
```

]);

Reference

> https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-required-if

Comment: That second `amount` key is going to overwrite the first for a start.

Answer (score -1):

to me best and quick way is using closures:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-closures

Comment: Provide an example from the code in the link; link-only answers are considered low-quality and are subject to closure if not updated.

Comment: @TimLewis so im waiting for the code of who ask...

Comment: Huh? I don't understand what that sentence is supposed to mean. What I'm saying is, provide a code example [in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69741252/edit) from the link you provided. You can't just post the link.